# How to stop IE from scrolling cursor into view

Tags: html, internet-explorer, scroll, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable iframe on a page with a fixed height and content that is longer so there is a scrollbar. If I scroll down to place the cursor in content at the bottom, then click a button outside the iframe that will move cursor to the top of the document. IE 8/9  will scroll back to the top of the iframe.

Is there anyway to stop IE from automatically scrolling?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXsYh/16/ (scroll down, select text, click button - it will scroll back to top)

Comment: Why wouldn't you want it to scroll?

Comment: part of a user requirement - we have a comment bar beside our editor with comments related to paragraphs. normally a user can click a comment and editor will scroll to the paragraph associated, but there's also a toggle button to stop scrolling.